# Magento 404 in all mobile browsers but normal is ok

Tags: magento, mobile, browser, http-status-code-404

We have an Magento CE 1.7.0.2. version, working perfectly on explorer, chrome, firefox. 
But all mobile browsers is gives an 404 page not found error (magento layout), I can't solve this problem. Has anyone alse seen this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you done some research on the error? I don't know anything about Magento, but you might want to mention its installation, and other relevant bits.

Comment: I have a theme from Galathemes installed, I've searched everywhere for this specific error, I found some other 404 errors and tried the solutions, without any luck. It is an error specific on mobile browsers with use of an not mobile theme.

Answer (score 0):

#

### redirect for mobile user agents

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]
```

#

check if these lines are uncommented in your .htaccess file.

Also in configuration what values defined for mobile theme.

Comment: I want mobile browsers to find the normal desktop theme, not a mobile theme. Why do I need to redirect in this case? Shouldnt magento load the default theme?

Comment: well probably some htaccess rules or some admin configuration is redirecting so comment those rules.If no .htaccess rules then check if there is any extension or core customization that is redirecting.